# Android , Java , drawing specific shape like arc

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

I want to create a customview which will draw a specific shape .
So I try to override the onDraw function of View class and draw a shape by canvas class . But I couldnt found the solution to draw what I want .
Here is the shape that I want to draw (the color part and the rest is transparent not white)

[Target shape](http://s15.postimg.org/s7k7kpq9n/Untitled_2.png)

Please help me !! Thanks all in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can create a white rounded corner in a layout which background is red (example code here : http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2318)